# Controlling a Visual Studio C++ application with an iPhone using Bluetooth

Tags: ios, visual-studio, sockets, bluetooth

I need to develop an iOS application in order to control my Visual Studio C++ application using an iPhone or an iPad.

The idea is to connect my iPhone/iPad to my Windows PC via Bluetooth.
The target is to use the iOS application as a client which can stream data (requests) to my Visual Studio C++ application (the server).

My doubt is: is this even possible?
Can I stream data from an iOS application to a Visual Studio C++ application using sockets?

Comment: Why bluetooth? This would be much easier to implement if you were to open a service on local wi fi network. There are way too many restrictions on bluetooth on iOS.

Comment: I thought about Bluetooth but I'm open to other solutions if they help simplifying the job. In this case I would need to install a wi-fi dongle on my Windows PC in order to have a private local network, am I correct?

Comment: As long as your iOS device (wi-fi) and PC (LAN cable) are on same local network you won't even need a 'wi-fi dongle' ... however, thats just the network connection part.... what you are trying to achieve is by no means trivial... you need peer to peer connectivity between your devices and the apps.. Look for something like http://openpeer.org ...